# how set a qt widget subproperty with StyleSheet

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qdockwidget, qtwidgets

I would like to set the QT QDockWidget DockWidgetClosable property using a StyleSheet .
However it's is inside 'features' property.

[image]

How can I change it using stylesheets?

I tried it without success.

For instance.

```
QDockWidget{
    qproperty-floating:false; 
    qproperty-windowTitle:omg12;  
}
```

Sets the parameter "floating" and "windowTitle" to those respective values. but I haven't found a key to set the "DockWidgetClosable" value.

Comment: You mean [:closable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#closable-ps) for example?

Comment: no @AlexisP. :closable is a state selector. I would like to Change this parameters. For instance. qproperty-floating:false; qproperty-windowTitle:omg12;  set the parameter "floating" and "windowTitle"

Comment: You can't change it with a style sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `QDockWidget` is pretty much considered a "class" in the .qss stylesheet - and if you want to modify the `DockWidgetClosable` property of all `QDockWidget` - you'll have to change the values of all the `QDockWidget` classes like so:

```
.QDockWidget{
    DockWidgetClosable: true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can change it with a style sheet actually, but not exactly as described above.

The only way I got it working was by directly calling the `qproperty-feature` and set its value to a string which contains each name of a sub-feature I want to use and separating them by the vertical bar symbol.

For example:

```
QDockWidget{
   qproperty-features:"DockWidgetClosable | DockWidgetFloatable | DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar";
}
```

#### Where did I find this information?

Unfortunately there is no direct information available, but I discovered a little hint when reading the online documentation:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#DockWidgetFeature-enum

There you can find a table for the enum constants and the corresponding values. One of the table entries caught my eyes:

| Constant | Value |
| --- | --- |
| QDockWidget::AllDockWidgetFeatures | DockWidgetClosable|DockWidgetMovable|DockWidgetFloatable |

From this entry I concluded that maybe the sub-features of the `qproperty-feature` can be set by their names and luckily it worked.